# touch: true not triggered when object is deleted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, fragment-caching

I have two models - Post and Comment. I'm using fragment caching to cache each `post` like so:

```
- @posts.each do |post|
  - cache post do
    = render 'posts/post', post: post
```

**post.rb**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, touch: true
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Now my `comments.rb` file is as follows:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post, touch: true
end
```

This works as expected. Whenever I add a new comment to a post, the cache key of that particular post expires. However, when I ***delete*** a comment from a post, the cache key of that post doesn't expire. What gives?